# Get year from Django DateTimeField with values()

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

What is the correct way to extract the year from a DateTimeField?

Example given:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('slug'), max_length=250, unique=True, default='', blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(_('content'))
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('created'), default=timezone.now)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(_('publish date'), blank=True, null=True)

    STATUS_ARTICLE = (
        ('DRAFT', _('draft')),
        ('PUBLISHED', _('published'))
    )

    status = models.CharField(_('status'), max_length=100, choices=STATUS_ARTICLE, default='DRAFT')

class ExtractMonth(Func):
    template = "EXTRACT(MONTH FROM %(expressions)s)"

    def __init__(self, *expressions, **extra):
        extra['output_field'] = models.SmallIntegerField()
        super().__init__(*expressions, **extra)
```

Trying to get a list of all the years, and number of articles per year:

```
result = Article.objects.filter(status='PUBLISHED').annotate(Year=ExtractYear('publish_date')).values('Year').annotate(dcount=Count('Year'))
```

This results in the following error:

```
near "FROM": syntax error
```

The resulting query is:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "articles_article"."publish_date") AS "Year", COUNT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "articles_article"."publish_date")) AS "dcount" FROM "articles_article" WHERE "articles_article"."status" = PUBLISHED GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "articles_article"."publish_date"), "articles_article"."created" ORDER BY "articles_article"."created" DESC
```

Comment: This seems like a complicated solution to what is supposed to be a straightforward use-case. Extracting the year from a datetimefield shouldn't require a developer to write custom SQL.  Also, in which module is "Func" defined?

Comment: Suggested solution does not work. Got the following error: near "FROM": syntax error

Comment: This the query that is being generated, I'm testing this locally on the sqlite database: SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "articles_article"."publish_date") AS "Year", COUNT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "articles_article"."publish_date")) AS "dcount" FROM "articles_article" WHERE "articles_article"."status" = PUBLISHED GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "articles_article"."publish_date"), "articles_article"."created" ORDER BY "articles_article"."created" DESC

Comment: Be more specific please. Are you referring to the MonthTransform solution in the ticket? I'm on Django 1.8, so 1.9 stuff will not help me.

Comment: @JeroenJacobs My answer was tested with Django 1.8.3, give it a try, I'd like to know if that helped you.

Comment: Ivan, DateTimePart is only available in 1.9, not in 1.8

Comment: Ivan, I appreciate your attempts to help me, but referring to undocumented internal functions of Django is not an acceptable solution to me. I cannot find any information on how this function is supposed to be called, what parameters it expects, or what it returns.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've ended up doing. Gocht's solution looks like it should work but I had problems (Django 1.10, SQLite) with Django handling the results. I didn't want to use `RawSQL` but that's the only thing I've got to work.

```
try:
    from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear
except ImportError:
    from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

qs = Article.objects.filter(...)

try:
    # Django >= 1.10
    qs = qs.annotate(Year=ExtractYear('publish_date'))
except NameError:
    # Django < 1.10
    qs = qs.annotate(Year=RawSQL(
            "CAST(SUBSTR('table_name'.'publish_date', 1, 4) AS integer)",
            ()
         ))

results = qs.values('Year').annotate(dcount=Count('Year'))
```

This makes `Year` an integer, rather than a string; remove the `CAST(... AS integer)` if you want a string.

You'll need to change the `table_name` to be whatever your model's database table is.

I'm not sure the `except NameError` is the best way to handle that, but I couldn't work out how better to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question a lot interesting. So I was playing with console for a while.

I followed the links provided by @Ivan and got this:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func
from django.db.models.functions import Substr

Article.objects.filter(...).annotate(_date=Func(F('publish_date'), function='LOWER'))
                           .annotate(publish_year=Substr('_date', 1, 4))
                           .values('publish_year')
```

This should give your the year as an string.

Note: this will work if in `_date` you get something like this: `u'2015-08-24 09:45:16'`, if you get a different string, you can change the indexes in `Substr('_date', 1, 4)`. You can see what kind of string you get in `_date` by adding it in `.values('_date', 'publish_year')`.

I hope this helps.

Extra:

This is the result I got:

```
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 24, 9, 45, 16), 'date3': u'2015', 'date2': u'2015-08-24 09:45:16'}, ...]
```

In this case, `date3` is for me the final result.

EDIT:

Generated SQL:

```
>>> print MyModel.objects.all().annotate(date2=Func(F('date'), function='LOWER')).annotate(date3=Substr('date2', 1, 4)).query
SELECT `app_model`.`id`, `app_model`.`date`, LOWER(`app_model`.`date`) 
AS `date2`, SUBSTRING(LOWER(`app_model`.`date`), 1, 4) 
AS `date3` FROM `app_model` ORDER BY `app_model`.`created` ASC
```

Comment: @Ivan This is a high-level solution I used only Django's ORM functions. I tested in a MySQL database, but I don't think this will case problems on sqlite, I updated my answer with the SQL statement created from the orm, it's not using any special function.

Comment: But EXTRACT won't work on sqlite, that's why I worked on this solution with simple functions using only ORM.

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, but when I try it (Django 1.10, using sqlite) I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'`. From the traceback, it looks like it successfully does the query, but then Django is trying to do some kind of conversion on what it thinks is a Datetime field, but is actually a string like `'2015'`.

Comment: It seems as though `django.db.models.sql.compiler.SQLCompiler.apply_converters()` tries to run `django.db.backends.sqlite3.operations.DatabaseOperations.convert_datetimefield_value()`, sending it `'2015'` as a value and `Substr(Func(Col(my_table_name, app_name.app_model.publish_date), function=LOWER), Value(1), Value(4))` as an expression.

Comment: @PhilGyford I didn't try with SQLite. Thanks for pinting it.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a build in function [TruncYear](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncYear)

Try this

```
result = Article.objects.filter(status='PUBLISHED').annotate(Year=TruncYear('publish_date'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
result = Article.objects.filter(status='PUBLISHED').values('publish_date__year').annotate(dcount=Count('id'))
```

publish_date__year extract the year value of the field.